# http get API to query cloud sql and return in csv

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-sql

I would like to expose my data to public who can query with get or post call:

```
www.my-domain.com/db1/table1?columns=['col1', 'col2']&rows-id=['id1','id2', 'id3']&output='csv'
```

I know I can make a microservice (like flask app) to do the job but I thought there might be a much easier solution: to create a database table on cloud sql and be done. Similar to the way cloud storage turns a bucket to a static website.

Is it possible?

What is the easiest way to store data tables that people can query through http api calls?

What would be your approach?

I appreciate your insightful answer.

Answer (score 1):

My comment is in context of AWS.

You can store your data in DynamoDb and then expose it using API Gateway.

See this [page](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/) for example

With this approach, there is no need to write any microservice using AWS Lambdas